# Key Command (shortcut) to automatically transpose notes in Nuendo or Cubase

Tags: keyboard, cubase

I am working on a large project and I have to use automation a million times in my project. I am trying to find some 'keyboard shortcut' for transposing notes up and down.

Maybe there's not a preset for this, and if that's true, would you please help me to assign some 'key command' for that?

Comment: If you really mean what I understand ( nodes = notes,  rise up and down = transpose, key command = shortcut) you might have the vocabulary to. search in the manual. I didn’t use cubase yet but I have downloaded a trial version of cubase V.

Comment: What up date version are you using and  which sytem? You should always tell wfen you have a „technical“problem.
This is a quite particular question. there are surely some cubase experts here. I know Doctor Mayhem 
is one es he recently said he’d be a cubase fan.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about Cubase is it has a 1,300 page manual.

The other thing is that, until you've read that manual at least 3 times, you're going to struggle.

All documentation is available via the Help Menu.

Everything is key-commandable - literally everything.
Every menu, every function, every user-made preset.

[image]

If you need harmonic transposition, then use the Transpose floater - ctrl/T to set it up & alt/T to action it.

[image]

If you need simple parallel transposition, then use the Logical Editor & make yourself some user-presets - that way you can transpose up or down without opening the edit floater again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts in notation programs usually can be created and edited by users while there are already some pre-existing ones. Cubase is probably not primarily a notation program but it must fit to solve your problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinberg_Cubase

If you haven‘t got the manual you first have to download this. (Look up for your language, your operating system and your download version of cubas)

(It seems you’re lacking the vocabulary to look up for your question. This difficulty is everyone‘s who doesn‘t speak English. And manuals aren’t easy to understand - even not in our mother language.)

https://helpcenter.steinberg.de/hc/en-us/articles/115000189090-Manuals-documentation-and-online-help

There are certainly different solutions for „rising upmand dowb the notes“. Look up presets, key edizor, toolbar, transpose, just go through it and if you have translation problems try google translator or you may also ask in the stack exchange site „english language“)

https://steinberg.help/cubase_pro_artist/v9/en/cubase_nuendo/topics/midi_editors/midi_editors_key_editor_inspector_r.html